# Unable to set additional permissions with existing AccessToken in android with Facebook sdk 4.0.1

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0

I was using `loginButton.setReadPermissions( "user_friends");` initially but i changed my permission to `loginButton.setReadPermissions( Arrays.asList("public_profile, email, user_birthday,user_friends"));`. Now i am not able to get required field from user profile And getting this error in logcat  Cannot set additional permissions with existing AccessToken.

**EDIT**

```
 protected void onCurrentAccessTokenChanged(AccessToken old, AccessToken newToken) {

        final ProgressDialog pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                newToken,
                new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(
                            JSONObject object,
                            GraphResponse response) {
                        // Application code


                        pDialog.dismiss();
                        Log.v("LoginActivity", response.toString());

                    }
                });
        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
        parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email,gender, birthday");

        request.setParameters(parameters);

        pDialog.setMessage("Loading Channels....");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
        request.executeAsync();


    }
};
```

I am getting null in birthday and email address. How can i fetch these two? Thanks in advance.

Comment: what are you trying to get ?

Comment: I want to fetch birthday and email from GraphResponse which i am using under onCurrentAccessTokenChanged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need to re-authenticate for basic information such as public profile, user friends and email. You can send graph request after successful login,

```
GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onCompleted(JSONObject object,GraphResponse response) {
    try {
            String  email=object.getString("email");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }               
});
request.executeAsync();
```

But in order to get the B'day, you have to submit the app for a review, read here [description](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login)

Comment: Still object.getString("email") is returning null. Is email is inner Jsonobject or may be i am using wrong key "email" ?

Comment: well, they do not guarantee that you will get email always, try with several accounts please.  No above sample is tested by my self and email key is correct.

Comment: But what about other information such as birthday and place user belong ?

Comment: As they mentioned, you can get "public profile, user friends and email" without submitting your app for review. For all other, you need to submit the app for review.

Comment: and what is this thing i am getting in logcat  "set additional permissions with existing AccessToken" can you explain ?

Comment: if it is asking for additional permissions, that is for user_birthday for sure. Because for other 3 permissions that you have mentioned above doesn't need "Additional Permissions"

Comment: Yes but my question is how can i give additional permissions and ask user for permission again ?

Comment: what are the additional permissions you need to request ?

Comment: If I want to add "publish_action" than ?